# Вывод очень маленьких чисел в консоли.

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы в консоли числа вида 9.6111е-008 выводились полностью и как можно их рассчитать по такому представлению?

Comment: Можно уточнить, что такое "рассчитать" в данном контексте?

Comment: @rugachavo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте печатать в формате `%.15g`

```
  double a = 1, b = 12345678910, c = 0.12345678920,
    d = 9.6111e-18, e = 9.6111e8;

  printf ("%.15g %.15g %.15g %.15g %.15g\n", 
          a, b, c, d, e);
```

Может, понравится...
(а вообще-то читайте man 3 printf).

Answer (score 1):

```
double x = 9.6111е-008;
cout << x << fixed << endl;
```

Comment: Может, наоборот: сначала `fixed`, потом значение?

Comment: Может, но у меня и так срабатывает как надо :)

Наверное, это больше от реализации компилятора зависит.

Comment: А в цикле пробовали?  
(именно вот это 9.6111e-8)